# Cant import WebMercatorViewport

Tags: javascript, es6-modules, deck.gl, javascript-import

For some reason I'm not able to import a module stored locally on my computer. I've included `type="module"`, spun up a Live Server using the VS Code extension and messed with the path name (., ..\ and ). There is also a TypeScript version of the package, that I tried to point to that would not work.

I also tried `{WebMercatorViewport}` and `WebMercatorViewport` in the import statement.

My code:

```
<script type="module">
        import {WebMercatorViewport} from '../node_modules/@deck.gl/core/dist/es5/viewports/web-mercator-viewport.js';
    </script>
```

The underlying file:

```
function WebMercatorViewport() {
    //bunch of code here
    return WebMercatorViewport;
}(_viewport.default);

exports.default = WebMercatorViewport;
(0, _defineProperty2.default)(WebMercatorViewport, "displayName", 'WebMercatorViewport');
```

You can clearly see that it's defined and it's the default.

But I still get this console error:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: ambiguous indirect export: default

This happens in both Firefox and Chrome.

Can someone help me diagnose this?